# How to fetch data from rest api by specific id or name using flutter

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart

This is the api I want to use and I want to get data on Only India.
I am not getting how to get the data by country name.

https://api.covid19api.com/summary

Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: If the API provides an endpoint that you can use the get filtered result, use that. If not,  get the `Countries` array from the response, and use [`where`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) to find the element in the list that contains data for India.

Comment: API documentation here: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc

Answer (score 1):

Either you can get the from this API and then select the data for India from the response or you can change the URL of the API a little bit and change it to

```
https://api.covid19api.com/country/india
```

you will get data for India only.